# Gibbs free energy and it's physical significance

Tags: thermodynamics

What is the physical significance of Gibbs free energy. I mean I can't correlate it with practical world?

Comment: Also posted on Chemistry SE. Cross posting is not considered appropriate on Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 0):

Gibbs free energy basically determines whether a reaction will be spontaneous (-ve) or non spontaneous (+ve). 
When a piece of sodium is dropped in water, it immediately reacts with water.
Hence, the process is spontaneous, i.e. it does not require a catalyst to drive it forward, or anything to initiate it.
In a non spontaneous reaction, a chemical reagent is required to force the reactants to react.